# How do I unmarshall JSON with unknown keys in Go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a question sort of like the following, but I am unable to understand the solution and mine might be slightly different:
[Trouble unmarshalling nested json with unknown keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505410/trouble-unmarshalling-nested-json-with-unknown-keys)

The difference between mine and the previous post is the unknown key is the first key while theirs is in the nested part.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "0": {
    "stats": {
         "name" : "x",
         "host" : "y"
    }
  "1": {
     "stats": {
         "name" : "x",
         "host" : "y"  
   }
  "...": {
     "stats": {
         "name" : "x",
         "host" : "y"  
   }

}
```

I am trying to use Go to unmarshall my JSON. The problem I am having is there is an unknown amount of instances. So there could be 0,1,2,... which is a key that I am getting. The rest nested under that number is known.

This is what I got so far:

```
type Stat struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Host string `json:"host"`
}

type Instance struct {
    Stats Stat `json:"stats"`
}

type App struct {
    Instance map[string]*Instance
}

func unmarshall(jsonappdetails string) {
    bytes := []byte(jsonappdetails)
    var p2 App
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &p2)
    fmt.Println(p2)
}
```

UPDATED: Solution

```
type Stat struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Host string `json:"host"`
}

type Instance struct {
    Stats Stat `json:"stats"`
}

type App struct {
    Instances map[string]Instance
}

func unmarshall(jsonAppDetails string) (appJSON *App) {
    bytes := []byte(jsonAppDetails) 
    appJSON = new(App)
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &appJSON.Instances)
    return appJSON
}
```

Comment: Also your `p2` should be an `App`, not `map[string]*App`

Comment: Sorry I fixed and didn't fix in my post. So I tried both of those and it still does not work.

Comment: I get this: {map[]}

Comment: I was wrong. You don't need an App. You need var `p2 map[string]*Instance`

Comment: @NorthrendGrizzly right, it should be just the map of instances, either declare app as `type App map[string]*Instance` or keep it as you it is now but instead of passing in `&p2` to unmarshal pass in the field, i.e. `&p2.Instance`. And fix your json as well. https://play.golang.org/p/KcT5Jn9fYXp

Comment: I tried the first one earlier and it did not work. The new suggestion did work though (second suggestion)! Thank you @mkopriva. If you want to make a post I can accept it as an answer. Also, how would I iterate through and access the host? Or to keep it simple, how would I get the host from instance 0?

Comment: Oh I figured it out: fmt.Println(p2.Instances["0"].Stats.Host)